# JavaScript: Adding if condition inside of a template variable

Tags: javascript, html, string, if-statement, ecmascript-6

I have a template variable in Javascript as below

```js
 var TABLE_ROW = '<tr class={{bgColor}}>'
            + '<td><input id={{ID}} type="checkbox" class="mysqlListCheckbox" checked="checked"/> <span style="padding: 7px;">{{COUNT}}</span></td>'
    + '<td><p class=text-warning>{{COMMENTS}}</p></td>'
    + '</tr>';
```

At this moment `ID` is always checked but I want to modify it such as `ID` should not be checked/selected if `COMMENTS` is empty.

I am new to Javascript template variables. Any reference links to achieve this are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What sort of template engine are you using? It's not a built-in Javascript feature. I imagine the JS text there gets transpiled through the engine before being served to the client?

Comment: That's just a string with something that is, by some additional custom JavaScript, "interpreted" as a "template".

Comment: Are you using a template engine or you just want to pass javascript variables in a string? If you just want to pass variables to a string in js, it works like `var TABLE_ROW  = \`some stuff here ${theVariable} and other stuff here.\` ` - the `\`\`` are very important. If you are using a template engine, you have to compile the string with the variables first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ternary operator (if the templating engine supports it):

```
var TABLE_ROW = '<tr class={{bgColor}}>'
            + '<td><input id={{ID}} type="checkbox" class="mysqlListCheckbox" checked={{COMMENTS == "" ? "" : "checked"}}/> <span style="padding: 7px;">{{COUNT}}</span></td>'
    + '<td><p class=text-warning>{{COMMENTS}}</p></td>'
    + '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to Javascript, please try to understand How JS works. JS as such does not provide any templating out of the box for template purpose you can use  HandleBars.js, in case of if you have used HandleBars. I would suggest you to use a helper function to handle this.

Link for handlebars
https://handlebarsjs.com/

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('decideSelect',function(param){
    if(param.COMMENTS.length==0){
        let Htmlstr =  '<td><input id='+param.ID+' type="checkbox" class="mysqlListCheckbox" /> <span style="padding: 7px;">'+param.COUNT+'</span></td>'+'<td><p class=text-warning>'+param.COMMENTS+'</p></td>';
        return Htmlstr;
    }else{
        let Htmlstr =  '<td><input id='+param.ID+' type="checkbox" class="mysqlListCheckbox" checked="checked"/> <span style="padding: 7px;">'+param.COUNT+'</span></td>'+'<td><p class=text-warning>'+param.COMMENTS+'</p></td>';
        return Htmlstr;
    }


});
};

var TABLE_ROW = '<tr class={{bgColor}}>'
    + '{{decideSelect this}}</tr>';
```